# How to draw a gradient outline facing outwards?

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.drawing

Using the `system.drawing` library in `.net-core`, is it possible given path:
[image]

```
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(1024, 512);
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    var curve = new[] { new PointF(0f, 0f), new PointF(32f, 31.794779f), new PointF(64f, 62.367702f), new PointF(96f, 90.54387f), new PointF(128f, 115.24048f), new PointF(160f, 135.50848f), new PointF(192f, 150.56894f), new PointF(223.99998f, 159.84314f), new PointF(255.99998f, 162.97466f), new PointF(287.99997f, 159.84315f), new PointF(319.99997f, 150.56895f), new PointF(351.99997f, 135.50848f), new PointF(384f, 115.24048f), new PointF(416f, 90.54386f), new PointF(448f, 62.367676f), new PointF(480.00003f, 31.794739f), new PointF(512.00006f, -5.3103886E-05f), new PointF(544.00006f, -31.794844f), new PointF(576.00006f, -62.36777f), new PointF(608.00006f, -90.543945f), new PointF(640.00006f, -115.24056f), new PointF(672.00006f, -135.50854f), new PointF(704.0001f, -150.569f), new PointF(736.0001f, -159.84317f), new PointF(768.0001f, -162.97466f), new PointF(800.0001f, -159.84311f), new PointF(832.0001f, -150.56888f), new PointF(864.0002f, -135.50836f), new PointF(896.0002f, -115.24033f), new PointF(928.0002f, -90.543686f), new PointF(960.0002f, -62.36748f), new PointF(992.0002f, -31.794533f), new PointF(1024f, 2.8495393E-05f) };

    var path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddCurve(curve);

    graphics.TranslateTransform(0, 256);
    graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Black, 16), path);
    graphics.ResetTransform();

    graphics.Dispose();
    bitmap.Save("outline.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

To use an arbitary gradient:
[image]

To draw a gradient outline that starts at the outer edges of the shape and progresses outwards to look like this?
[image]
(Example was created via [photopea.com](https://www.photopea.com/) layer style stroke, with a "Shape Burst" style gradient)

Comment: Just in case, try something. `graphics.DrawPath` with a normal white pen and set its width = 20. `graphics.DrawPath` again with a black **compound pen**, width = 16. To create the compound pen: `var pn = new Pen(Color.Black, 16);` and set `pn.CompoundArray = new[] { 0, .1f, .25f, .75f, .9f, 1 };`.

Comment: So close and yet so far. The output is similar to the desired result, and I might have accepted needing to make as many calls as there are colors in the arbitrary gradient, but there's no blending between the black and white lines. Thanks for sharing!